# Is clang correct to warn of a binding to a temporary value?

Tags: c++

In this code, clang warns that `v` will be bound to a temporary value. I expect it to be bound to one the variables that's defined outside the function. Is clang correct?

```
std::vector<int> a, b, c;

void foo()
{
    static auto const& v = [](){ /* logic to return a or b or c */ }();
}
```

Comment: `[]() -> std::vector<int>& {...`, it assumes you want to return a copy not a reference. You can use `auto&` too.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Aaah! My goodness, that's right!

Comment: @jaggedSpire even then, the temporary lifetime should be extended by binding to `v` so there is no problem? I would have expected such a warning in the case that a dangling reference was created

Comment: @M.M I'm not sure why it's a warning myself. Certainly it's helpful here, but I can't see it being the case every time...

Comment: @jaggedSpire oh, maybe it has to do with the `static` ... the reference will persist across calls but the temporary dies when the function returns

Comment: @M.M seems like on [gcc at least the bound temporary persists across calls](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc57c4eb43bc073d)

Comment: @M.M if I'm reading the standard right, [class.temporary/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6) means the bound temporary persists for the lifetime of the static reference rather than the scope in which is was created.

Comment: @screwnut may I ask what settings you got that warning on? With clang 3.8 and -Weverything under c++14 I'm [not getting that warning.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e94b32a0a6be7d13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're binding a temporary to a reference there. The lambda is returning a copy of your chosen vector, not a reference to it.

You can see this is the case if you try to alter the bound vector after the first call to foo:

```
void foo()
{
    static auto const& v = [](){ return a; }();
    std::cout << v.size() << '\n';
}
...
foo();
a.push_back(1);
foo();
a.push_back(2);
```

will print

```
1
1
```

<sup>see it on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cf871d980033b5a)</sup>

Just do

```
static auto const& v = []() -> auto& { /* logic to return a or b or c */ }();
```

instead and you're good.

Comment: static auto const& v = []() -> auto& { /* logic to return a or b or c */ }(); will not work. You need to return rt.

Comment: rt? I find myself unfamiliar with the term and unable to deduce from context what you mean.

Comment: (please elaborate on what you mean by "rt" and how, precisely, this does not work. RT is an acronym I've never seen before -- do you mean a "reference type" or *l-value*? an *r-value*?)